# How to Inject javascript in an iframe loaded by UIWebView - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, uiwebview

I am listening to this delegate method on `UIWebView`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
```

On which, I apply some javascript using

```
[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:myscript];
```

Whereas the delegate method is appropriate to listen to the end of an iframe request, it seems that my js does not apply on the iframe. It applies to the main document of the uiwebview.

Is there a way to do that : How can I inject js on iframes on a iOS `UIWebView` object ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your JS.  You can run operations on your iframe object just fine, in the "myscript" from your question, you will need to run your JS commands on the

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow
```

object. Or, if you are not referring to the first iframe in your UIWebView, use another selector to refer to the iframe you are attempting to refer to.

Comment: How about iframes which are inaccessible because of cross-domain security restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some API of iOS I don't know about, you can only execute Javascript in the context of the top-level document by calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:myscript`.

Luckily, since 2013 (when the last answer was written) we now have [window.PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and [crypto.subtle.generateKeys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey) which lets you generate a non-extractable key in the iframe, and pass the public key to the iOS using [addScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller/1537172-addscriptmessagehandler?language=objc). Each iframe should receive a unique id and be told what it is, either via the `window.location.hash`, or via `postMessage`. It should send this id to the native code, along with a unique index/key of the native call and the public key to encode stuff with. (The native code can also check the `iframeInfo` on the message, to make sure that the request is coming from the proper domain.) Finally, the native code can call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:myscript` on the WebView, and pass the payload *encrypted with the public key*, along with the iframe's id and the index/key of the all, to the iframe using `postMessage`. The iframe will decode it, and call the appropriate callback. You can implement a complete Cordova-like bridge in this way, using iframes!

Note that the authors of the top-level document have chosen to render your iframe and thus no incentive to mess with the delivery of the message. However, the message must be encrypted because they may have a strong incentive to steal information!

PS: If you are worried about quantum computers breaking cryptography, then you may have to use a symmetric key instead of public-private key pair, or just not send the public key along with the payload :)